# Xamarin Forms UWP page looks blank on local machine but works on Windows 10 phone

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have an app created with the latest Xamarin.Forms 2.3 and tested it with a Lumia 550 Phone.

The page contains some custom `Entry`, a `DatePicker` and a `Button`.

The app on the phone works perfectly but on the local machine, I only get a blank screen (only with this page).

Phone:

[image]

Local machine (upgraded with Creators Update):

[image]

A few months ago, they both worked with Xamarin.Forms 2.2.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView x:Class="MyProject.Views.UserDataView"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Caliburn.Micro.Platform.Xamarin.Forms"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
             xmlns:component="clr-namespace:MyBaseProject.Component;assembly=MyBaseProject"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyBaseProject.Converter;assembly=MyBaseProject"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             Padding="0">
    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:BoolConverter x:Key="boolConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>            
            <Label Grid.Row="0"
                   Style="{DynamicResource BoldField}"
                   Text="Input1:" />
            <component:CustomEntry Grid.Row="1"
                                    Keyboard="Text"
                                    MaxLength="100"
                                    Text="{Binding Param1.Value1}" />            
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Input2:" />

            <DatePicker Grid.Row="3"
                        Date="{Binding Param1.Value2}"
                        Format="yyyy.MM.dd"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />            
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label x:Name="lblCF"
                       Style="{DynamicResource BoldField}"
                       Text="Input3:" />
                <Label FontAttributes="Italic"
                       IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference cfEntry}, Path=IsOK,Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}}"
                       Text="(invalid)" />
            </StackLayout>
            <component:CustomSNEntry x:Name="cfEntry"
                                       Grid.Row="5"
                                       MaxLength="11"
                                       Text="{Binding Param1.Value3}}" />            
            <Label Grid.Row="6" Text="Input4:" />
            <component:CustomEntry Grid.Row="7"
                                    Keyboard="Text"
                                    MaxLength="70"
                                    Text="{Binding Param1.Value4}}" />

            <Label Grid.Row="8" Text="Input5:" />
            <component:CustomEntry Grid.Row="9"
                                    Keyboard="Text"
                                    MaxLength="70"
                                    Text="{Binding Param1.Value5}" />            
            <Label Grid.Row="10" Text="Input6:" />
            <component:CustomEntry Grid.Row="11"
                                    Keyboard="Text"
                                    MaxLength="10"
                                    Text="{Binding Param1.Value6}" />            
            <Label Grid.Row="12" Text="Input7:" />
            <component:CustomEntry Grid.Row="13"
                                    Keyboard="Text"
                                    MaxLength="100"
                                    Text="{Binding Param1.Value7}" />            
            <Label Grid.Row="14" Text="Input8:" />
            <component:CustomEntry Grid.Row="15"
                                    Keyboard="Telephone"
                                    MaxLength="15"
                                    Text="{Binding Param1.Value8}" />            
            <Button Grid.Row="16"
                    cm:Message.Attach="Save"
                    Style="{DynamicResource BasicButton}"
                    Text="Save" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentView>
```

The custom components (`CustomEntry` and `CustomSNEntry`) are descendants of the Entry class with a Behavior added to them.

What should I do about this?

**UPDATE 2:**

The issue still persists and it looks like the following *default style* causes the problem:

```
 <Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="components:MyEntry">
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
      <Setter.Value>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="18"
                         Tablet="28" />
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
      <Setter.Value>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="40"
                         Tablet="50" />
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

I don't know why.

If I remove the `Height` setter and leave the `FontSize`, it shows *nothing*.

If I remove the `FontSize` setter and leave the `Height`, it shows *only the labels*.

If I remove both of them, it shows *everything normal*.

Comment: You should post ideally the sample project to reproduce the problem or at least your xaml. Is 2.3 the latest?

Comment: Please show more detail code!

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Please check my initial post.

Comment: @Nestor I found that you used lot of `Binding` and `DynamicResource`. So I could not reproduce your issue with your segment code. Could share a 
complete simple project ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I can't create a simple project based on this project as it contains copyrighted code, and any other simple project can't reproduce the issue. What could cause this type of difference between a phone and a computer? The target architecture (x86 vs. ARM)?